# Create a Hyperlink in Word using Matlab activeX

Tags: matlab, hyperlink, ms-word, activex

Currently I am trying to write some Text to Word using ActiveX and Matlab. This file: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9112-writetowordfrommatlab
helped me a lot. But I can't figure out how to insert an Hyperlink to Word.

e.g. I want to add the the word "test" connected with "www.test.de".

I've tried this:

```
ActXWord = actxserver('Word.Application');
ActXWord.Visible = true;
trace(ActXWord.Visible);  

word_handle = invoke(ActXWord.Documents,'Add');

ActXWord.ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add('test','www.test.de');
```

and also some other combinations with the

```
ActXWord.ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add
```

method. But Matlab doesn't know the .Add method. I found some Excel examples which are working like this, but for Word it doesn't work. Somebody has an idea whats the problem could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is not really related to MATLAB. You are not calling the `Add` method of the ActiveX component correctly.

This should work:

```
link = 'www.test.de';
ActXWord.ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter(link);
ActXWord.ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add(word_handle.Range(0, length(link)), link);
```

Anyway, this is not related to MATLAB; for more information you should refer to [MS Word VBA reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee861527.aspx).

Comment: Thank you! This works, but now the whole text in the document is a Hyperlink. How can I precise the range for a certain word (e.g. test)?

Comment: @deSteini I've updated the answer so that not all the text in the document becomes a hyperlink.